# How to use glPixelTransfer, glTexEnv and glRasterPos in openGL 3.1?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

`glPixelTransfer`, `glTexEnv` and `glRasterPos` have been deprecated in OpenGL 3.1. What is it replaced with? If not replaced, how can I get a similar effect? I would like to use these functions.

Comment: @Nicolas Bolas: glPixelTransfer, obviously.

Comment: It's a very interesting question insofar as both the OpenGL 3.3 and 4.2 man pages of `glTexImage[123]d` explicitly say that components are multiplied with `GL_c_SCALE` and added to `GL_c_BIAS`, which is kind of pointless if you're not allowed to use the only function that can set these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it replaced with?

Framebuffer objects and fragment shaders.

P.S. If you don't want to mess with shaders, you can keep using older OpenGL version, you know.

Comment: Can you give me more detailed instructions on how to use   Framebuffer objects and fragment shaders? Thank you .

Comment: @yaya: That's a very big topic you're asking about.

Comment: @yaya: That would take a lot of time. Search for tutorials or read books about OpenGL 3. opengl.org has a list of recommended literature: http://www.opengl.org/documentation/books/

Comment: @yaya: There's a pretty good OpenGL Wiki article on [Framebuffer objects.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) And there are several [online tutorials](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) for getting up to speed in OpenGL 3.x.

Comment: give me some advice to  realize the function of glixelTransfer、glTexEnv and glRasterPos  with Framebuffer objects and fragment shaders ? I know the question I asked is complex, yet I need to use them  now . Think you vety much!

Comment: @yaya: It's not possible to explain it quickly. You can transfer pixels using framebuffers to render to texture (and there may be other ways). For implementing glTexEnv, you'll need to write your own fragment shader (a program that calculates color for every pixel of object you render). It is a big topic. If you're in a hurry, either hire somebody to do it for you, or keep using older version of OpenGL - OpenGL 2.0, for example.

Comment: Thank you , your answer is enough for me .I don't need the specific implementation method . I would like to know What direction to go .Although ,my expression isn't accurate, but I hope you can understand . You give me advice about glTexEnv . Well , can you give me some advice about glixelTransfer and glRasterPos. As a new to openGL, I don't know how to express my gratitude to you .